# Java OOM Automatic Heap Dump File Name in K8S

Tags: java, kubernetes, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-dump

An answer to this question is available at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077693/1525813 but not from a Kubernetes perspective.

For my k8s app, I specify the JVM options as an environment variable in the k8s YAML (below). This has been giving issues where the pod crashes on container start-up (running Linux) as the command substitution isn't working as expected.

**ENV VAR**

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        command: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
        args:
          - exec java $JVM_OPTS -jar myapp.jar
#         - exec startup.sh # For few other apps
        env:
        - name: JVM_OPTS
          value: >-
            -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
            -XX:HeapDumpPath=/logs/heapdump/hd_$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S)_pid$$.hprof
            -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError
            -XX:OnError=/scripts/threaddump.sh
            -XX:ErrorFile=/logs/error/hs_err_$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S)_pid$$.log
            -Xlog:gc*=debug:file=/logs/gc/gc_%t_pid%p.log:time,uptimemillis,pid,tid,level,tags
```

**ERROR LOGS on container startup**

```
Error: Could not find or load main class +%F_%H-%M-%S)_pid$.hprof"
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: +%F_%H-%M-%S)_pid$.hprof"
```

What am I missing here?

---

#### SUB-QUESTION

The earlier config was `-XX:HeapDumpPath=/logs/heapdump/hd_%t_pid%p.hprof` which was not interrupting the container start-up but the heap dump file was being created with the name `hd_%t_pid%p.hprof` i.e. `%t` and `%p` were not being substituted for `-XX:HeapDumpPath` but were substituted for `-Xlog:gc*`.

What could be the cause of discrepancy here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See for details https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/112645

> I added these values for JVM_OPTS in a shell script and used it to invoke the JAR. Then invoked the script from the k8s YAML args.